# Issue while File upload using ajax submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my `index.php` I have a form where a file upload will happen

```
 <form id="uploadImage" method="post" action="upload.php">

                                    <span class="input-group-text">

                                        <label for="attach-doc" class="attachment-icon mb-0">

                                            <i data-feather="image" class="cursor-pointer lighten-2 text-secondary"></i>

                                            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" accept=".jpg, .png" /> </label></span>
                                    </form>
```

I have a jquery for ajax submit as

```
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function(){

    $('#uploadImage').ajaxSubmit({
    // target: "#editor1 .ql-editor",
    // resetForm: true
    });
 });
```

And my `upload.php` code is

```
<?php

//upload.php



if(!empty($_FILES))
{
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $allow_ext = array('jpg', 'png');
        if(in_array($ext, $allow_ext))
        {
            $_source_path = $_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'];
            $target_path = 'upload/' . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($_source_path, $target_path))
            {
                echo '<p><img src="'.$target_path.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="160" /></p><br />';
            }
            //echo $ext;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

File locations are :[image: File Location]

So as per the code when I click on the `upload file` a ajax call should happen and the image should be uploaded to the folder upload .

But upload is not happening with the above code, Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Did you include the jQuery Form Plugin (because `ajaxSubmit()` is not a standard jQuery method) correctly?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: We're going to need some more specifics than "not happening". Have you done any proper debugging?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked the network tab (in the browsers dev tools) if a request is made, what data (if any) it sends and what the response is? Have you checked the web servers error log for PHP errors? Have you debugged to see if `$_FILES` are empty or not? Have you checked the value of `$_FILES['uploadFile']['error']`? Please do some basic debugging and report your findings.

Comment: Basically Image is not uploading to the `upload` folder

Comment: Also check the file permissions on the upload folder (it's the user your web server runs as that needs write permissions)

Comment: Does the folder './upload/' exist? If that's not the problem, turn on all error reporting on your server and see what the response is in the network tab of the dev tools.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine on my system. Only one error was coming for ajaxsubmit() function which is not a part of jquery. So i added this <script src="https://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script> and then file is being  uploaded on my upload folder. Check again for permissions to your upload folder.

Comment: And what's the name of the file you're trying to upload? Your PHP code only allows for `jpg` and `png` in lower case (and will reject if those are in upper case).

Comment: @VirenderKumar Is there any ways to debug the php code say echo the file name in upload.php page?

Comment: @ShreyasAchar You can debug your code if you want by supplying more ajax submit options. See this document for help https://malsup.com/jquery/form/#sample2

Answer (score 1):

You have missed one form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that is used for file uploading.

If the form tag does not have this attribute, then your file will not be uploaded to the server.

Please change following line:

```
 <form id="uploadImage" method="post" action="upload.php">
```

to

```
<form id="uploadImage" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I hope this will work for you

Comment: This is irrelevant because the upload is happening via AJAX, not a standard form submission. Not sure why this was upvoted.